# Can we use ions in space to propel and power spacecraft?

Tags: electromagnetism, space, propulsion

If space contains mostly ions (whether positive or negative), then why cant a spacecraft “absorb” them with simple anodes/cathodes, separate them, and repurpose the ions for spacecraft electricity (e-) or propulsion (p+)?

Comment: Space contains mostly nothing

Comment: Actually it contains just vacuum.  Found an article that might help on ion propulsion. https://www.nasa.gov/centers/glenn/about/fs21grc.html

Comment: For a fun take on this, have a read of Tau Zero. It is more about the threat of ions in deep space than the opportunity but quite a good way of thinking about it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tau_Zero

Answer (score 2):

Ions are indeed used to provide thrust for spaceships, and this type of motor is called an [ion thruster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_thruster).

This providers thrust in basically the same way as a conventional rocket motor. If the ion thruster fires out an ion of mass $m$ with velocity $v$ then the momentum of that ion changes by $mv$. Since total momentum is conserved the momentum of the spaceship has to change by $-Mv$, where $M$ is the mass of the spaceship. So firing the ion out one way makes the spaceship accelerate in the other direction.

The thrust produced by the motor is equal to the rate of change of momentum, so it's given by:

$$ F = \tfrac{m}{t} v $$

where $m/t$ is the mass of ions ejected per second i.e. the number of kilograms per second of ions that the motor spits out the back. The thrust is actually quite small. Ion thrusters produce only a small force but they produce it continually so over time the speed increase builds up to a substantial value. For example the thrusters used in the [Dawn probe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawn_(spacecraft)) produce only $90$ mN or the force produced by a $9$ gram weight at Earth's surface.

Anyhow the point of all this is that the ion thruster engine only works if the spaceship has enough mass of propellant to keep the thruster running for long periods. Dawn carried [$425$ kg of propellant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawn_(spacecraft)#Propulsion_system) to fire out of its engine.

Your idea would work fine if Dawn could capture that $425$ kg of matter in its travels, but the problem is that there simply isn't that much matter available in interplanetary space. I've struggled to find a definitive statement of the density of interplanetary space. A figure of 1 hydrogen atom per cubic centimetre seems to be mentioned a lot, so let's take that figure but bear in mind it may not be terribly accurate.

Anyhow at 1 hydrogen atom/cc space contains about $10^{-22}$ kg per cubic metre. Suppose you fitted Dawn with a one square metre collecting grid then it would have to travel over $10^{24}$m to collect the $425$ kg of matter it held in its tank. That's about a billion light years!

I'd regard that figure with some scepticism because the figures for the density of interplanetary space probably aren't very reliable. However I think it makes the point that there is far too little matter floating around out there to be useful for propelling a spaceship.

Comment: Thanks, @John Rennie. What if the space craft were to loop through more matter-dense and gravitationally-strong regions of space on its travels, say close to stars? Given a starting payload of matter like Dwan to launch with, and the correct flight plan to visit nearby stars on the way to its destination (like the tacking of a sail boat), would this allow the spacecraft to capture sufficient matter and use the slingshot effect around the massive bodies to reach a few hundred lightyears, for instance?

Comment: @SteveAlbarran No because there aren't any matter dense regions to hand. Suppose we wanted to send a probe like Dawn to the nearest star. Once the probe has left the Solar System there is basically nothing for four and a half light years.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hand-waving arguments as to why it might be difficult.

The EM force is much stronger than gravity but long range interactions are dominated by gravity so either there aren't many ions or space is mostly electrically neutral. It's probably the latter so you are likely to hit as many positively charged particles as negatively charged ones which will make it difficult to extract energy from them.

Answer (score -1):

My quess would be quantity. Space has a lot of ions but its also a whole lot of nothing.

The interstellar medium has a density of between 1E-4 ions per cm^3 and 1E+6 molecules per cm^3. By comparison sea level has about 10^19 molecules per cm^3.
So space is just that, space.

Copper has about 8.5E+22 free electrons per cm^3. So theres not anywhere near enough ions in open space to conduct any kind of power for a craft.

Comment: Hi Joe. Bearing in mind that this site is, [and I quote from the tour](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tour), *a question and answer site for active researchers, academics and students of physics and astronomy*. We expect answers to be fairly detailed. For example you could give figures for the density of matter in space and how much thrust could be obtained by using that matter in an ion drive. As it stands your answer is basically just a comment.

Comment: Please elaborate @Bigjoemonger

Comment: Well you're not wrong. It was just a comment. Unfortunately this site does not let me post comments until my rep hits 50. Unless its in response to my own answer. And the only way to increase rep, that i know, is to post answers. So unfortunately at this point all i can do is post answers. Don't blame me. Blame the flawed design of the site.

Comment: @Bigjoemonger that's good info, thanks. **However, your reply doesn't really answer my question.** While I knew that space is mostly vacuum and the density of interstellar medium is very low, I am still wondering if it is possible to (a) capture the sparse ions available for meaningful use on a spacecraft, and (b) if the expulsion of the collectable positive ions out the back of the craft are sufficient to propel a craft of reasonable size (e.g. a typical cubesat) at a rate of acceleration that would justify further research into this form of propulsion?

Comment: If you join one Stack Exchange community first, and get some points there, you start off on 100 when you join another. That might help you in the future.